# Unable to put two divs on same line and telling controls to take more width if available

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am building this app with React and Material UI. I am using the autocomeplete control.
Here is the [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vxkv2?file=/demo.js)

issues

1. I want two auto complete control to appear on same line. I tried setting display:"inline" css to the div. But its getting overwritten by default style which is weird. How can i ensure both the controls appears on the same line.
2. Once, both the control appears on same line, I want them to take 20% width each. Which means together they will take 40% width. Then as I add more item to these controls, I want it to expand width wise until together they reach 100% width. After that control should increase the height in order to show more items.

Answer (score 0):

from your explanation i say you need to set

```
item: {
    minWidth: "20%",
```

and for the root :

```
 root: {
    maxWidth:'100%',
    display: "flex !important"
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here. The main problems:

1. You're not using flex on the root and the items
2. You're defining a fixed `width` on the items, as opposed to a `maxWidth`

[See this version which I think does what you're hoping.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o02vc) I also removed your margin rule and added `flex-grow: 1` to the items, and sets the root width to `100%` rather than a fixed value in pixels.